# Textarea - Limit content per line

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex-spark

Is there anyway I can limit the content of a text area per line?

For instance, in case an user paste a text which overflow that "predefined" number of line, the textarea will just display the content until the limited value previously set up. Keep in mind that empty lines should be take in count.

Any help will be welcome.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application name="Spark_TextArea_limit_lines"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private const MAX_LINES:uint = 5;

            private function textChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
                //Split the string into an array of lines
                var lines:Array = textArea.text.split("\n");
                //If there are too many lines...
                if (lines.length > MAX_LINES) {
                    //Clear the existing text
                    textArea.text = "";
                    //Then insert MAX_LINES of the previous text
                    for (var i:uint=0; i<MAX_LINES; i++) {
                        textArea.text += lines[i] + "\n";
                    }
                    //Finally, move the cursor to the end of input, as
                    //it is reset to position 0 when the text is modified.
                    textArea.selectRange(textArea.text.length, textArea.text.length);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea id="textArea" change="textChangeHandler(event)"/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that doesn't keep the empty lines.

For example, in this case all lines will be joined.

Line 1

line 2

line 3

Comment: The problem with this approach is that doesn't keep the empty lines.

For example, in this case all lines will be joined.

Line 1

line 2

line 3

Answer (score 0):

it works with `\r`

```
var lines:Array = textArea.text.split("\r");
```